# How to bind an object across other tabs in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

I am having a table at the backend, so when a query is asked at the frontend for an object, all the tabs in the front end should be populated with the details of the query object. I am able to pick the query object at the back end , but i dont know how to bind that object across all the tabs in flex. I am getting an error type coercion failed, cannot convert X to mx:Array collection. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without code example its tricky to answer. But the following should help.

Rather than trying to convert the query result to an Array, step through each of the query result objects,... not sure what form this is in, but if its xml for instance, generate objects for each of the xml nodes/elements (however suits best),  and add them individually to the Array.

Hope this helps

Comment: One other thing. The tabs that have not yet been opened, may not have been initialized yet.